# How do I create a blurred effect section of a CCLayer in Cocos2d?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, blur, cclayer

Is there any way to "make" a rectangular section of a CCLayer blurred?

Either by making a masking layer over the game layer, or by actually blurring part of the game layer?

Comment: Nice question..Can you get section of cclayer as texture?? If you can than please see this link:http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/gaussian-blur-implemented-in-cocos2d/ It might help you.

Comment: i think , you can achieve this by changing texture  you use as your layer using something like this blur:texture. you can also check this    http://labs.freescapes.org/blog/main/blur-for-cocos2d-texture-on-retina-displays/

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess I found an answer...

https://github.com/manucorporat/AWTextureFilter/tree/master/AWTextureFilter

Its pretty cool.